# Laravel Nova card localization

Tags: localization, laravel-5.6, laravel-nova

I'm trying to add localization support for a [card](https://nova.laravel.com/docs/1.0/customization/cards.html) built for the Laravel Nova dashboard.

I already created a folder in `/resources/lang` containing the JSON language files in a format like `en.json`. The files get published (copied) with the publish command but the `loadJsonTranslationsFrom()` does not seem to do anything:

```
class CardServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
  public function boot()
  {
    $this->publishes(
      [__DIR__ . '/../resources/lang' => resource_path('lang/vendor/my-custom-card')],
      'my-custom-card-lang'
    );

    $this->loadJsonTranslationsFrom(resource_path('lang/vendor/my-custom-card'));
  }
}
```

This is how the markup in `Card.vue` looks like:

```
{{__('Title')}}
```

How can I test if the JSON files are loaded correctly? What am I missing?

The question is how do I support localization for cards in Laravel Nova?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Card localization [has been solved](https://github.com/laravel/nova/pull/521) in Laravel Nova 2.

To localize strings use the `__` helper within your Vue components and load the according translation files within your `NovaServiceProvider`:

```php
Nova::serving(function (ServingNova $event) {
    Nova::script('{{ component }}', __DIR__.'/../dist/js/card.js');
    Nova::style('{{ component }}', __DIR__.'/../dist/css/card.css');
    Nova::translations(__DIR__.'/../resources/lang/en/card.json');
});
```

An exemplary implementation can be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/radermacher/nova-current-environment-card/pull/6/commits/373beb64f50489fdba1461e884789651ba736022).

Further information is now available in the [documentation](https://nova.laravel.com/docs/2.0/customization/localization.html#frontend).

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same issue, but for a [tool](https://nova.laravel.com/docs/2.0/customization/tools.html), also in Nova 2.0.
I found a somewhat elegant solution - maybe it helps someone nonetheless.

- Create en.json in `/nova-components/{your-tool}/resources/lang/`
- In `/nova-components/{your-tool}/resources/js/tool.js` add `Vue.mixin(require('./translation'));`.
  It should look something like this:

  > ```
  > Nova.booting((Vue, router, store) => {
  >     router.addRoutes([
  >         {your-routes}
  >     ]);
  >     Vue.mixin(require('./translation'));    <-------------- add this line!
  > });
  > ```
- Create the `/nova-components/{your-tool}/resources/js/translation.js`, it should look like this:

  > ```
  > module.exports = {
  >     methods: {
  >         __(key, replace) {
  >             var translations = _.merge(window.config.translations, window.config['tool-translations']);
  >             var translation = translations[key]
  >                 ? translations[key]
  >                 : key;
  >
  >             _.forEach(replace, (value, key) => {
  >                 translation = translation.replace(':' + key, value)
  >             });
  >
  >             return translation;
  >         }
  >     }
  > };
  > ```
- Now you have to add the following to the `Nova::serving()` function inside the `boot()` function of your `/nova-components/{your-tool}/src/ToolServicePrivoder.php` file:

  > ```
  > Nova::provideToScript([
  >     'tool-translations' => $this->getTranslations(),
  > ]);
  > ```
- Now add below said `boot()` function the following:

  > ```
  > private static function getTranslations()
  > {
  >     $translationFile = __DIR__ . '/../resources/lang/' . app()->getLocale() . '.json';
  >
  >     if (!is_readable($translationFile)) {
  >         return [];
  >     }
  >
  >     return json_decode(file_get_contents($translationFile), true);
  > }
  > ```

Comment: Nova docs is failing us once again, in the docs they only mention the en.json file, not that we need all this code to get it working